# Location of POM file in multi-module project for use in Maven Deploy Plugin

Tags: maven, build.gradle, gitlab-ci

I have a multi-module Gradle project (which generates 3 artifacts per module, the sources, javadoc, and main jar). I need to generate a `.pom` file for my project for use with the Maven Deploy Plugin which is installed on an image that Gitlab CI uses. I have a (WIP) script which generates a `.pom` file with gradle, but I'm unsure of exactly *where* or how many `.pom` files I need for all of my modules.

Questions:

1. Where exactly should I be generating a `.pom` file(s) so that the
   Maven Deploy Plugin can see it when I run `mvn deploy:deploy` in the
   Gitlab yaml file?
2. Do I need a separate `.pom` file for each group of module artifacts?

Any help would be appreciated! Especially some sort of example of someone generating a `.pom` file with Gradle and then deploying with the Gitlab CI.

Comment: Just a comment from the Maven side: You usually have one pom per main artifact, so the pom "represents" the sources and javadoc as well.

Comment: Why do you need to use maven-deploy-plugin cause you are already using gradle which can deploy the artifacts ?...

Comment: @khmarbaise I guess I'm not really sure of the best practice in this case. I can deploy it with the gradle script *or* with the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file (which can take bash commands). Is it better to deploy with the gradle script? And if so, would I need a single POM per module, or just one POM for all the modules?

Comment: @JFMeier Thank you. So, to confirm, I would need one pom file per module? (each module generates the 3 artifacts)

Comment: and also, where do I put the Pom files? In the same output folder as the artifacts? Or at the root of each module?